# has_one validates_associated firing inconsistently despite 'on: :create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, has-one, validates-associated

I'm seeing really weird behaviour when checking `valid?` on a model that has a `validates_associated :contact, on: :create`. If I make two calls to `valid?` the first is `true` and the second is `false`.

This is a minimal version of the models, hopefully it's enough detail:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact

  accepts_nest_attributes_for :contact

  validates_presence_of :contact
  validates_associated :contact, on: :create

  delegate :postcode,
           :phone_number,
           to: :contact
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :country

  validates_format_of :phone_number, if: :logged_in_australian?, allow_blank: true
  validates_format_of :postcode, if: :logged_in_australian?, allow_blank: true

  private

  def logged_in_australian?
    logged_in? && australian?
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_user && current_user == user
  end

  def australian?
    country && country.name == 'Australia'
  end
end
```

The behaviour I'm seeing in the controller is an infinite redirect between two actions:

```
  def dashboard
    flash.keep if !parent.valid?
    return redirect_to complete_signup_parent_path if !parent.valid?
    # other stuff
  end

  def complete_signup
    return redirect_to action: "dashboard" if parent.valid? #&& parent.valid?
    # other stuff
  end
```

If I uncomment the `#&& parent.valid?` it stops redirecting, which seems just insane.

The parents this happens for have an invalid `phone_number`, but the requirements around the `phone_number` changed after they signed up so we don't want to hassle them about it. So the desired behaviour is to get `valid?` to be `true`, and it is initially, it's just on subsequent calls it changes.

I've put in some debug statements and I can see that the validate context is `:update` for every call. So it shouldn't be running the `validates_associated`. These are also created parents, so there shouldn't be a `:create` or `new_record?` in play. Another debug statement proves that validations are running on contact, including the one for phone_number, but only the second time it gets called in an action.

I also put in a breakpoint and could see that `parent.valid?` returned true and then false, and also that if I break before `valid?` gets called and call `parent.contact_detail` and then `parent.valid?` then it returns false.

Why is the second call to `parent.valid?` validating `contact` even though it's only supposed to do that `on: :create`?

Answer (score 0):

To tell without rest of code, it is hard. Are @parent and parent pointing towards the same object?

Results differ when `#&& parent.valid?` is uncommented which leads me to think that `@parent.valid? && parent.valid?` != `@parent.valid?`

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to know how much context to include.

Comment: I meant to write just `parent` everywhere. It's just an attr_reader for `@parent`, so yeah, they're the same thing. As I said, I can call `parent.valid?` twice (or `@parent.valid?` twice) in a debug console and get true and then false. What could cause it to validate the contact even though it's in an `:update` context?